# Converting WAV to MP3 in ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am writing a script that lets a user record their voice and then saves the file as an MP3 format.  I'm recording using http://code.google.com/p/micrecorder/ which works fine and the WAV is saved.  However, I need to convert that file, on the drive, to mp3 before I move it along the pipeline.

I have a lot of experience in the PHP/Python/Ruby/C world, but this is my first foray into AS3, any ideas?

Comment: Do you -need- to do it in Action script? did a quick google search... and apparantly iTunes has the ability (for free): http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/how-to-convert-wav-file-into-mp3-file-with-itunes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do it in Flash with [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/), but I think you should send your WAV (or raw data) to a server, encode the file server side and send it back to the user. From what I've seen, even with Alchemy, the encoding is too slow and hang the UI.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following MP3 encoder:

http://code.google.com/p/flash-kikko/

It works for me!